# Recommend me a webapp that allows paste from clipboard to a web page/web app/window where the clipboard is converted to whatsapp text formatting?

Tags: web-apps, text-editor, whatsapp

Using this [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+formatted+WhatsApp+messages+with+ease+to+paste+in+WhatsApp+Web) I found a [webpage](https://deeppradhan.heliohost.org/misc/whatsapp-text-formatter.htm) which you could paste into and get back Whatsapp text formatted text. So it replaces **bold** with *bold* and *italics* with _italics_ etc. Unfortunately that webpage is down.

EDIT: Unfortunately when the webapp came back up it didn't do exactly what I wanted. I want it to convert clipboard to whatsapp text formatting like this [webapp](https://euangoddard.github.io/clipboard2markdown/) does for [clipboard to markdown](https://euangoddard.github.io/clipboard2markdown/)

What other similar webapps are out there?

Comment: It's up again. Check it out!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wil reedit the question; It doesn't do what I want. I want a webapp that does similiar to [clipboard2markdown](https://euangoddard.github.io/clipboard2markdown/) except for whatsapp text formatting.

Comment: Why did my question get a negative. Is it a formatting issue?